# How to define mergeExpressions for a custom DeclarativeAggregate (in catalyst package)

Tags: apache-spark

I don't understand the general approach one takes to determine the mergeExpressions function for non-trivial aggregators.
The mergeExpresssions method for something like org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.Average is straightforward:

```
override lazy val mergeExpressions = Seq(
    /* sum = */ sum.left + sum.right,
    /* count = */ count.left + count.right
  )
```

The mergeExpressions for CentralMomentAgg aggregators is a bit more involved.
What I would like to do is create a WeightedStddevSamp aggregator modeled after sparks CentralMomentAgg.
I almost have it working, but the weighted standard deviations that it produces are still a little off from what I compute by hand.
I'm having trouble debugging it because I do not understand how I can compute the exact logic for the mergeExpressions method.
Below is my code. The updateExpressions method is based on this [weighted incremental algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#cite_note-9), so I'm pretty sure that method is correct. I believe my problem is in the mergeExpressions method. Any hints would be appreciated.

```
abstract class WeightedCentralMomentAgg(child: Expression, weight: Expression) extends DeclarativeAggregate {

  override def children: Seq[Expression] = Seq(child, weight)
  override def nullable: Boolean = true
  override def dataType: DataType = DoubleType
  override def inputTypes: Seq[AbstractDataType] = Seq(DoubleType, DoubleType)

  protected val wSum = AttributeReference("wSum", DoubleType, nullable = false)()
  protected val mean = AttributeReference("mean", DoubleType, nullable = false)()
  protected val s = AttributeReference("s", DoubleType, nullable = false)()
  override val aggBufferAttributes = Seq(wSum, mean, s)
  override val initialValues: Seq[Expression] = Array.fill(3)(Literal(0.0))

  // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Weighted_incremental_algorithm
  override val updateExpressions: Seq[Expression] = {

    val newWSum = wSum + weight
    val newMean = mean + (weight / newWSum) * (child - mean)
    val newS = s + weight * (child - mean) * (child - newMean)

    Seq(
      If(IsNull(child), wSum, newWSum),
      If(IsNull(child), mean, newMean),
      If(IsNull(child), s, newS)
    )
  }

  override val mergeExpressions: Seq[Expression] = {
    val wSum1 = wSum.left
    val wSum2 = wSum.right
    val newWSum = wSum1 + wSum2
    val delta = mean.right - mean.left
    val deltaN = If(newWSum === Literal(0.0), Literal(0.0), delta / newWSum)
    val newMean = mean.left + wSum1 / newWSum * delta                //  ???
    val newS = s.left + s.right + wSum1 * wSum2 * delta * deltaN     //  ???
    Seq(newWSum, newMean, newS)
  }
}


// Compute the weighted sample standard deviation of a column
case class WeightedStddevSamp(child: Expression, weight: Expression)
  extends WeightedCentralMomentAgg(child, weight) {

  override val evaluateExpression: Expression = {
    If(wSum === Literal(0.0), Literal.create(null, DoubleType),
      If(wSum === Literal(1.0), Literal(Double.NaN),
        Sqrt(s / wSum) ) )
  }

  override def prettyName: String = "wtd_stddev_samp"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered how to write the mergeExpressions function for weighted standard deviation. I actually had it right, but then was using a population variance rather than a sample variance calculation in evaluateExpression. The implementation shown below gives the same result as above, but it easier to understand.

```
override val mergeExpressions: Seq[Expression] = {   
    val newN = n.left + n.right
    val wSum1 = wSum.left
    val wSum2 = wSum.right
    val newWSum = wSum1 + wSum2
    val delta = mean.right - mean.left

    val deltaN = If(newWSum === Literal(0.0), Literal(0.0), delta / newWSum)
    val newMean = mean.left + deltaN * wSum2
    val newS =  (((wSum1 * s.left) + (wSum2 * s.right)) / newWSum) + (wSum1 * wSum2 * deltaN * deltaN)

    Seq(newN, newWSum, newMean, newS)
}
```

Here are some references

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance
- http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/ch2/weightsd.pdf
- http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/fanf2/hermes/doc/antiforgery/stats.pdf
- https://blog.cordiner.net/2010/06/16/calculating-variance-and-mean-with-mapreduce-python/ (This last one gave me the clue I needed for the mergeExpressions function)

Davies' post gives an outline of the approach, but for many non-trivial aggregators, I think the mergeExpressions function can be quite complex and involve advanced math to determine a correct and efficient solution. Fortunately, in this case, I found someone who had worked it out.

This solution matches what I work out by hand. Its important to note that the evaluateExpression needs to be modified slightly (to be s / ((n-1)*wSum/n)) if you want sample variance instead of population variance.

Answer (score 4):

For any hash aggregation, it's divided into four steps:

1) initialize the buffer (wSum, mean, s)

2) Within a partition, update the buffer of the key given all the input (call updateExpression for each of input)

3) After shuffling, merge all the buffer for same key using mergeExpression. wSum.left means wSum in left buffer, wSum.right means wSum in the other buffer

4) get the final result from buffer using valueExpression